# got panic on Rust Future executor block_on async when return the Error

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I tried to return error on `future::executor::block_on` but I always got panic when I return back to handlers

here is my code

```
    fn insert_one<T>(
        &self,
        col_name:
        EnumCollectionModel,
        doc: T,
    ) -> Result<(), ErrorIdentifier>
        where
            T: Borrow<mongodb::bson::Document>
    {
        executor::block_on(async {
            let col = self.db.database.collection(col_name.as_str());

            col.insert_one(doc, None).await.map_err(|err| {

                if err.to_string().contains("E11000 duplicate key error collection") {
                    return ErrorIdentifier { // doesn't return this
                        code: ErrorGlobal::Repository,
                        message: "Duplicate".to_string(),
                    };
                }

                return ErrorIdentifier { // doesn't return this
                    code: ErrorGlobal::Repository,
                    message: err.to_string(),
                };

            }).expect("TODO: panic message");
        });
        Ok(())
    }
```

the error I got is

```
thread 'actix-rt|system:0|arbiter:0' panicked at 'TODO: panic message: Error
```

the simple repro here

```
use futures::{executor, TryStreamExt};

fn inser_one() -> Result<(), Error> {

  executor::block_on( async {
   let init = do_something.await //
   
   init.map_err(|e| {
      Err("error here") // the error here not return and got panic
    })

 });
 Ok(()) 
 
}
```

is that something I missed here ???
how I can return that error in `::block_on` on my case above

I always can't get the error return `ErrorIdentifier` on here when I tried to make the API error

Comment: Could you clarify your problem a bit more? If you're trying to return a Result from `col.insert_one`, why even have an `expect` there after it?

Comment: because my idea said `Unused Result<InsertOneResult, ErrorIdentifier> that must be used ` if I don't wrap it with expec

Comment: my problem is I didn't get those `ErrorIdentifier` when I tired to make my API error

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I did edit my question , :) and the example case is the code above, @ChayimFriedman

Comment: Yes, but it is not _reproducible_ (and perhaps not _minimal_ either). We need something we can run by ourselves. Or at the very least, tell us what is every type and function.

Comment: I hope my edited question with example use case help to reproducible @ChayimFriedman

Comment: "Simple repro" doesn't compile - [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=328202d5629c29f1571e1f50f340ca01).

Comment: @iuerui If you paste a [MRE], please make sure it actually works and produces the error. That means, please also show `use` statements and the `main` function. Further, make sure it actually produces the error message; yours says `cannot find value do_something in this scope`, `cannot find type Error in this scope` and `expected ';', found 'init'`. If anything, your 'simple repro' is less complete and raises more questions than your original code.

Comment: The previous commend of mine is kind of nitpicky; most of those things can in fact be fixed by us, it's just annoying to have to do that because it takes time. That said, I tried to fix your [MRE], but I'm not sure how to do so. What's the point of the `map_err`? It literally doesn't do anything. Further, it won't compile, because its return `Err` value is has an ambiguous type, as it is discarded right away. Further, I'm not sure what `do_something` should do- it seems rather important what exactly it returns. So guessing what it might return is really not possible much.

Comment: I tried to fix it to the best of my abilities, but it produces no error: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=b40f188cdc1d3a4d9ff207ebf579e5d1

Comment: `expect` panics if it sees an `Err` in a `Result` type. The error you're seeing in your terminal is exactly the one you put in the `expect` call (`"TODO: panic message"`). So you're panicing (via `expect`) and seeing the panic message. Isn't this exactly what you intended?